# Read Adyen CreateCheckoutSessionResponse object as json string

Tags: http, c#-3.0, blazor-webassembly, adyen

My app is a Blazor Web Assembly client .net server...
I am calling my server (succesfully) to create a 'CreateCheckoutSessionResponse' object and return it to the client.
Looking at the browser, the response is a json coded string. This is from the debug preview tools in the chrome browser, looking at the response.. which seems fine:
[image: Chrome Browser Preview]

Initially, I tried to just bring this into a CreateCheckoutSessionResponse object in the client service that calls the server:

```
            public async Task<CreateCheckoutSessionResponse> GetAdyenPaymentSessionAsync(string userId, decimal amount)
            {
                AdyenSessionRequestDTO request = new AdyenSessionRequestDTO(userId: userId, currencyCode: "GBP", amount);
                var response = await _http.PostAsJsonAsync(Routes.GetAdyenSessionRoute, request);
                CreateCheckoutSessionResponse? res = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<CreateCheckoutSessionResponse>();
                return res;
            }
```

But, to instatiate the drop-in, I need to pass this session response as Json. The CreateCheckoutSessionResponse oject has a '.ToJson()'

So the complete call looks like this:

```
        AdyenSessionResponse = await _transactionService.GetAdyenPaymentSessionAsync(_userService.CurrentUser.Id, CreditWanted);
        AdyenSession = AdyenSessionResponse.ToJson();
        await _JS.InvokeVoidAsync("setAdyenCheckoutConfiguration", AdyenSession, _transactionService.AdyenPublicClientKey);
```

I haven't really been able to get as far as debugging the javascript to see if the dropin gets instatiated, because the CreateCheckoutSessionResponse seems to be corrupted when operated on '.ToJson'.

[image: Error message from the JS function]

This is the object after '.ToJson' loaded into a VSCode json view page:

```js
'{\n  "channel": "Web",\n  "amount": {\n    "currency": "GBP",\n    "value": 0\n
    },\n  "countryCode": "NL",\n  "expiresAt": "2023-03-31T12:06:39+01:00",\n  "lineItems": [\n    {\n      "amountExcludingTax": 0,\n      "amountIncludingTax": 0,\n      "description": "Site Credit",\n      "quantity": 1,\n      "taxAmount": 0,\n      "taxPercentage": 0\n
        }\n
    ],\n  "merchantAccount": "RedRocksTechnologyLtdECOM",\n  "reference": "000000113",\n  "returnUrl": "/redirect?orderRef=000000113",\n  "sessionData": "Ab02b4c0!B…c41T7F8gRuFdA/gf8NaFUV5OrVDhhMpKKaQp5ntwqhCmir9tvpqT+/z8/BsrrxmaseRwD06DHDbgtlqM40QV8IXV7kw7uIsoZVX8A9Ce+mAROdLvmQhrYZRX1psj0bZTWN/2fkiqTQhNHt6fYvBfZu0sTmhDiSt4f+E9TRjjChCFVeIU4iL7SLbh+3vVoIKWLxon7+DfImyPxrSNKrPDH18s+O4Ak1d5MyJYjrRXPSlrUxboI5Yfh6wLYDUrgvOpLR+sOBoL5bSqsOMX3FFKk8d6vbaRRaN2olMVqbHO7KYxJ/sKbKDoyDfTpeR/CojQSSabA4a45Ot7vMtPVhRy4eKfk4zWijeJSYC7ku0jK6ke9tJpIbUNaEYb3bthhgsc1ryYf8Ufz",\n  "shopperLocale": "en-US",\n  "splitCardFundingSources": false,\n  "threeDSAuthenticationOnly": false\n
}'
```

Which to be honest, doesnt look very much like good json...

So, I thought maybe a different approach...
Rather than use the 'CreateCheckoutSessionResponse' object, I'll try to read the json, straight out of the http response.. Chenged the the functions to this:

```
             public async Task<string> GetAdyenPaymentSessionAsync(string userId, decimal amount)
            {
                AdyenSessionRequestDTO request = new AdyenSessionRequestDTO(userId: userId, currencyCode: "GBP", amount);
                var response = await _http.PostAsJsonAsync(Routes.GetAdyenSessionRoute, request);
                string? jsonresponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                int length = jsonresponse.Length; // For Debugging

                return jsonresponse;
            }
```

Which I think should just return the raw string.. right? But when I do that, I am losing a lot of the information...

```js
'{
    "channel": 3,
    "recurringProcessingModel": null,
    "shopperInteraction": null,
    "accountInfo": null,
    "additionalAmount": null,
    "additionalData": null,
    "allowedPaymentMethods": null,
    "amount": {
        "currency": "GBP",
        "value": 0
    },
    "applicationInfo": null,
    "authenticationData": null,
    "billingAddress": null,
    "blockedPaymentMethods": null,
    "captureDelayHours": null,
    "company": null,
    "countryCode": "NL",
    "dateOfBirth": null,
    "deliverAt": null,
    "deliveryAddress": null,
    "enableOneClick": null,
    "enablePayOut": null,
    "enableRecurring": null,
    "expiresAt": "…WMF4620wYAkhfLNzoDj2DP2NBpYUjm8gP0DY6MOTlcb0omHNkf7gQADv6eZMCq6tw+KQKtN8+XtAwCWQYdgrE7G+dj1KW0vlKPKJzv7dOloB8m/vXpkhZFBlfej0uTHJ0ir9BOoxKYjRv6mh3+e4VZeVjjsCfIrW8kfgYbnZ/ERb0Q==",
    "shopperEmail": null,
    "shopperIP": null,
    "shopperLocale": "en-US",
    "shopperName": null,
    "shopperReference": null,
    "shopperStatement": null,
    "socialSecurityNumber": null,
    "splitCardFundingSources": false,
    "splits": null,
    "store": null,
    "storePaymentMethod": null,
    "telephoneNumber": null,
    "threeDSAuthenticationOnly": false,
    "trustedShopper": null
}'
```

So I am losing something in the 'ReadAsString' functionality.

Any pointers where this could be going wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I think I solved it. The text is being decoded with UTF8 as a default.

```
        Stream? jsonresponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        string res;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(jsonresponse, Encoding.ASCII))
        {
            res = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return res;
```

This returns the correct information.