# Deserialise Json Object to pass to JS function Interop from Blazor

Tags: javascript, c#, json, blazor-webassembly, adyen

I am using Blazor WASM and I want to accept payments using a JS drop-in from Adyen.
I have actually managed to make it work, see this question: [My previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75897570/read-adyen-createcheckoutsessionresponse-object-as-json-string/75899336#75899336)

But to some extent I don't understand why?.

A (what looks like good JSON) response comes back from the server. This was copied from the browser debug windown into a VSCode file and formatted:

```
    {
    "channel": 3,
    "recurringProcessingModel": null,
    "shopperInteraction": null,
    "accountInfo": null,
    "additionalAmount": null,
    "additionalData": null,
    "allowedPaymentMethods": null,
    "amount": {
        "currency": "GBP",
        "value": 300
    },
    "applicationInfo": null,
    "authenticationData": null,
    "billingAddress": null,
    "blockedPaymentMethods": null,
    "captureDelayHours": null,
    "company": null,
    "countryCode": "GB",
    "dateOfBirth": null,
    "deliverAt": null,
    "deliveryAddress": null,
    "enableOneClick": null,
    "enablePayOut": null,
    "enableRecurring": null,
    "expiresAt": "2023-04-17T11:28:00+01:00",
    "id": "CS2387F156F0520AB5",
    "lineItems": [
        {
            "amountExcludingTax": 0,
            "amountIncludingTax": 300,
            "description": "Site Credit",
            "id": null,
            "imageUrl": null,
            "itemCategory": null,
            "productUrl": null,
            "quantity": 1,
            "taxAmount": 0,
            "taxPercentage": 0
        }
    ],
    "mandate": null,
    "mcc": null,
    "merchantAccount": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "merchantOrderReference": null,
    "metadata": null,
    "mpiData": null,
    "recurringExpiry": null,
    "recurringFrequency": null,
    "redirectFromIssuerMethod": null,
    "redirectToIssuerMethod": null,
    "reference": "000000276",
    "returnUrl": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
    "riskData": null,
    "sessionData": "Ab02b4c0!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",
    "shopperEmail": null,
    "shopperIP": null,
    "shopperLocale": "en-US",
    "shopperName": null,
    "shopperReference": null,
    "shopperStatement": null,
    "socialSecurityNumber": null,
    "splitCardFundingSources": false,
    "splits": null,
    "store": null,
    "storePaymentMethod": null,
    "telephoneNumber": null,
    "threeDSAuthenticationOnly": false,
    "trustedShopper": null
    }
```

From the previous question, I was deserialising this as ASCII and passing it in to my JS interop code as follows:

```cs
Stream? jsonresponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
string res;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(jsonresponse, Encoding.ASCII))
{
    res = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
return res;
```

The calling function does this: (AdyenSession is a string, ObjRef is to allow the JS to callback)

```
AdyenSession = await _transactionService.GetAdyenPaymentSessionAsync(_userService.CurrentUser.Id, amount);
objRef = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
await _JS.InvokeVoidAsync("setAdyenCheckoutConfiguration", AdyenSession, _transactionService.AdyenPublicClientKey, objRef);
```

For completeness, the JavaScript code starts with this:

```js
var AdyenJsonObject;
var RawAdyenJsonObject;
var checkout;
var dropinComponent;

async function setAdyenCheckoutConfiguration(AdyenSessionResponse, passedKey, dotnethelper) {

    console.log(AdyenSessionResponse);
    RawAdyenJsonObject = AdyenSessionResponse;
    AdyenJsonObject = JSON.parse(AdyenSessionResponse);
    ...
```

When I break at the JSON.parse line above, the value (again formatted in VSCode) is:

```
    {
    "environment": "test",
    "clientKey": "test_AGQHLB7CRNA3BMHWPBIUOBNI4QZGVK6F",
    "analytics": {
        "enabled": true
    },
    "session": {
        "id": "CS55FA4A6E3BD028CB",
        "sessionData": "Ab02b4c0!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"
    },
    "paymentMethodsConfiguration": {
        "card": {
            "hasHolderName": true,
            "holderNameRequired": true,
            "billingAddressRequired": false
        }
    }
}
```

Which again looks like good json, except a lot of it is missing.

The input string to this looks like this:

```
    '{
    "channel": 3,
    "recurringProcessingModel": null,
    "shopperInteraction": null,
    "accountInfo": null,
    "additionalAmount": null,
    "additionalData": null,
    "allowedPaymentMethods": null,
    "amount": {
        "currency": "GBP",
        "value": 300
    },
    "applicationInfo": null,
    "authenticationData": null,
    "billingAddress": null,
    "blockedPaymentMethods": null,
    "captureDelayHours": null,
    "company": null,
    "countryCode": "GB",
    "dateOfBirth": null,
    "deliverAt": null,
    "deliveryAddress": null,
    "enableOneClick": null,
    "enablePayOut": null,
    "enableRecurring": null,
    "expiresAt"…/ToM4g9D/DcEDzm6xqKEzNVIMPmWtFtaXILQlOsn1q9LNSojuJYXTVxv12hfNb/s0yYDae3YXzS7et5rdLYvzS5aeeCUsj+Yajy3x9+f/OwqKLpqXVGIOkQ4hijH85jusgxxbW35yaWgHQfEjOdbtTX200VlvbsajGSdLKEMWtLcTHtb","shopperEmail":null,"shopperIP":null,"shopperLocale":"en-US","shopperName":null,"shopperReference":null,"shopperStatement":null,"socialSecurityNumber":null,"splitCardFundingSources":false,"splits":null,"store":null,"storePaymentMethod":null,"telephoneNumber":null,"threeDSAuthenticationOnly":false,"trustedShopper":null}'
```

If I look at the 'expiresAt' field it doesn't look particularly out of the ordinary does it?
From the raw data above...

```
"enableRecurring": null,
"expiresAt": "2023-04-17T11:28:00+01:00",
"id": "CS2387F156F0520AB5",
```

Something odd is definitely going on, or just that I don't understand.

Other things I have tried:
Reading as a byte[] array:

```
byte[]? arrayres = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
```

This reads the array, but again when I try to decode it into ascii or utf-8 string it I get the same result (breaking at expiresAt - or the JSON.parse just barfs...)

I also tried using c# JsonNode object but again a similar problem.

In an Ideal world the Adyen.Model.Checkout c# object 'CreateCheckoutSessionResponse' would just read back from the response, but it doesn't.

Ideas anyone?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the built-in `.ToJson()`  function in the Adyen .NET library, see: https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-dotnet-api-library/blob/main/Adyen/Model/Checkout/CreateCheckoutSessionResponse.cs#L762 - this should take care of the (de)serialization of the models.

I see that you're trying to sessions, an example of the `/sessions`-endpoint can be found here as well: https://github.com/adyen-examples/adyen-dotnet-online-payments/blob/main/checkout-example/Controllers/ApiController.cs#L55-L57

Let me know if this works for you :)

Comment: I tried that... in fact I tried just trying to load it into the CreateCheckoutSessionResponse object using their own objects. They don't work.

I did solve it though by creating my own Object to read it into.  I found a 'Tip'  on the MS help here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0

I will post an answer properly in a day or so.  I can only conclude that the Adyen Lib has a bug in it. I reported it onto the github pages last friday, but so far no response.

Comment: Also, I appreciate your help, but you misunderstand my question. I need to make it clearer maybe, but I am succeeding getting the session back to my server. It is getting back to my client which is the issue. Normally that will be in Javascript, and Angular, React etc frameworks all load that as JSOn directly. I am using BLAZOR Web Assembly so the libraries are probably being taken where they have never been before...

Comment: I see, let's have a look. Which library version are you using and could you perhaps share a part of the code so I can take the steps needed to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Are you at Adyen?  I am using the latest live 9.x release .. not the v10 beta. The server is sending the json as shown from the browser so that is OK. I will add some sample code when I get back to my desk. Tomorrow now sadly.